# Umbraco Custom MemberService and MembershipProvider

Tags: umbraco

We have a fairly large project that will get a redesign and we want to introduce Umbraco as CMS.

First off i have 0 (zero) experience and my Co devs also have only basic experience with Umbraco.

The lead Dev decided we keep our Users(Frontend) only in our own DB and therefore write a Custom MembershipProvider and Member Service.

I was assigned that Task and after researching i feel this is not the way to go, finding no resources at all covering that topic.

What is the preferred way to use existing users in a new Umbraco installation?

Br

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to write a custom membership provider and personally I don't particularly like the member interface in Umbraco but if that's the way to go for you then the CMSImport  package works well (license required - 99 euros). We've used it in the past and it was very straightforward.

Here is the project page https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport

Wing

Comment: I'd agree with this. I've implemented custom membership providers in the past when it's been absolutely necessary, but unless there's a solid requirement for this (shared authentication across systems for example), I'd import the users if they're only going to be used in the Umbraco site.